# jQuery full screen confirm with timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a web based production tracking system. My users are not reading the screen so I am build a full screen alert and confirm function to make them. Alert are to stay on the screen for 15 seconds to slow the user down and make learn from their mistakes. Confirm is to show the question for 15 seconds before then can give an answer, if no option is selected I want the confirm to fade out after 30 second. Below is what I have so far.

What I can't get to work is when one of the options is selected to return true or false. Also this works if I just call the function,but when I assign it to a variable just get skip over and the rest of the code is executed. I want it to act like a confirm. Thanks for your help.

```
function fullScreenAlertConfirm(msg,confirmOpt){

    var returnVar;

    $('body').append("<div class='alert'></div>");

    if(confirmOpt != null || confirmOpt != false){

        $('div.alert').html(msg+"<br> This Message will disappear after 30 seconds <br> Selection options will appear in 15 sec");

        $('div.alert').append("<div class='confirmBox'></div>");
        $("div.confirmBox").hide();
        $('div.confirmBox').append("<div class='no'>NO</div> <div class='yes'>YES</div> ")
        $("div.confirmBox").delay(15000).fadeIn(400);

        $("div.no").click(function(){

            $('div.alert').fadeOut(400);

            return false;

        });

        $("div.yes").click(function(){

            $('div.alert').fadeOut(400);

            return true;

        });

        $('div.alert').delay(30000).fadeOut(400);

    }else{

        $('div.alert').text(msg+"<br> This Message will disappear after 15 seconds");
        $('div.alert').delay(15000).fadeOut(400);
         return true;
    }
}

fullScreenAlertConfirm("Are you sure you want to change to the next shift?",true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tQkKh/1/

One of the ways I need this function to work.

```
//Change Shift
$("#change-shift").click(function () {

    var confirmShift = fullScreenAlertConfirm("Are you sure you want to change to the next shift?",true);
// var confirmShift  = confirm("Are you sure you want to change to the next shift?");

    if(confirmShift == false){
        window.location = 'orderControl.php';
        return;
    }

    $("#loading").fadeIn("fast");

    var request = $.ajax({
        url:'process.php',
        type:'POST',
        async:false,
        data:{mode:'change_shift'}
    });

    request.done(function (data) {

        var objData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

        if(objData.results == false){
            $("#loading").fadeOut("fast");
            $('body').append("<div class='error'>" +objData.errorMsg+"<br> This Message will disappear after 15 seconds</div>");
            $('div.error').delay(15000).fadeOut(400);

        } else if(objData.results == true){
            window.location = 'orderControl.php';
        }
    });

    request.fail(function (xhr) {
        alert('AJAX Error: ' + xhr.statusText);
    });

});
```

A jsFiddle example: for how I would like to use it.
http://jsfiddle.net/tQkKh/3/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is happening because jquery queues the "fadeout after 30s" event, and then when you click yes/no, this new event to fade out is then queued to happen afterwards.

To clear out this queue, append `.stop(true, true)` before your fadeOuts like:

```
$('div.alert').stop(true, true).fadeOut(400);
```

Comment: That works for when the function is called without being assign to a variable. When assign to a variable like :  var confirmShift = fullScreenAlertConfirm("Are you sure you want to change to the next shift?",true);. The process is shown for a second then the goes on to the ajax call that is after. It does not give you the chance to answer or test the variable for true or false.